# AngularJS ng-repeat through complex and dynamic JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I am trying to display the contents to the user from JSON Array using the `ng-repeat` option. The `JSON Array` is created dynamically so I am bit confused how to display the same to users.

The syntax of the `JSON ARRAY` is as follows, the content of `COMPLEX key` can increase or decrease dynamically:

```
jsonList    =   [
                    {
                        name    :   "AB",
                        local   :   "CD",
                        complex :   [
                                        name    :   "EF",
                                        local   :   "GH",
                                        complex :   [
                                                        name    :   "IJ",
                                                        local   :   "LL".
                                                        complex :   ........
                                                    ]
                                    ]
                    },
                    {
                        name    :   "PQ",
                        local   :   "RS",
                        complex :   [
                                        name    :   "TU",
                                        local   :   "VW",
                                        complex :   [
                                                        name    :   "XY",
                                                        local   :   "Z1".
                                                        complex :   ........
                                                    ]
                                    ]
                    }
                    ......
                ];
```

I am just confused how can display this to users.

I want it to look something like this where the user has the option to add the `complex` values at every step using the `Add Another` option:
[image]

I am really confused how to store the values in `JSON Array` automatically and loop though it using the `ng-repeat` and display to users automatically. Since the `JSON Array` is not fixed and can vary at every point, can someone please help me with some logic on how to proceed for this issue.

I tried to display in `HTML Table` but confused how to loop when there is so many `complex` objects.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a self-referencing component. I have an example here, based on your data. Note that the component uses itself in its template. This makes sure that it can continue forever if it wants to

```js
function myComponentController() {
  this.addNode = function(el) {
    el.complex.push({
      name: "New name",
      local: "New local",
      complex: [],
    });
  }
}

const myComponentConstructor = {
  controller: myComponentController,
  controllerAs: "$ctrl",
  bindings: {
    data: '=',
  },
  template: `
    <div ng-repeat="el in $ctrl.data" class="block">
      <span>Name: {{el.name}}</span>
      <my-component data="el.complex"></my-component>
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.addNode(el)">Add another</button>
    </div>
  `,
}

const app = angular
  .module("app", [])
  .component("myComponent", myComponentConstructor);
```

```css
.block {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <my-component data='[{
    name: "AB",
    local: "CD",
    complex: [{
      name: "EF",
      local: "GH",
      complex: [{
        name: "IJ",
        local: "LL",
        complex: []
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    name: "PQ",
    local: "RS",
    complex: [{
      name: "TU",
      local: "VW",
      complex: [{
        name: "XY",
        local: "Z1",
        complex: []
      }]
    }]
  }]'></my-component>
</div>
```